# Capistrano and EC2: Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano

When I run the command

```
cap deploy:cold
```

then in the deployment process I get these errors:

```
*** [err :: myapp.com] rake aborted!
*** [err :: myapp.com]
*** [err :: myapp.com] Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'
*** [err :: myapp.com]
*** [err :: myapp.com]
*** [err :: myapp.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
*** [err :: myapp.com]
```

Then I checked what everything was deployed - I went to the **releases** folder and there are only these files:

```
LICENSE          REVISION  lib  public  tmp
README.markdown  Rakefile  log  spec    urbanairship.gemspec
```

What happened with the rest (like **app** folder for example)?

**EDIT:** Deploy file:

```
set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "devel"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
set :application, "myapp"
set :repository, "git@github.com:name/myapp.git"
set :scm, :git

set :deploy_to, "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/myapp"
set :use_sudo, :false
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

before "deploy", "check_production"
```

Comment: Have you run `cap deploy:setup` first?

Comment: 1. `cap deploy:setup` -> ok, 2. `cap deploy:check` -> ok, 3. `cap deploy:cold` -> the error above.

Comment: Cam you post your `deploy.rb` file?

Comment: Hello, please, see the updated oP.

Comment: Is the database created on the server? I read from capistrano [documentation](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-from-the-beginning#about-deploycold) that `deploy:cold` is not recommended. try: `cap deploy`